# Correct way to handle this in Promise or Callbacks (JavaScript ES6)

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

Is there a correct or "better" way to handle `this` is JavaScript classes with-in Promises (or Callbacks even)

Currently I have just getting around this by doing this

```
 var self = this;
```

But this feels 'hackey' to me.

*Ignore most of the code below, it's just to get my point across.*

```js
 class thing {
  drawthing(thing) {
  console.log(thing); 
  }

  updatethings(thing) {
      var self = this;  //a better way to do this
      return new Promise(function (resolve) {
           setTimeout(function(){
               self.drawthing(thing);
               return resolve(thing);
           },2000);
      });
  }
}

var t = new thing();
t.updatethings('hello').then(console.log);
```

Comment: Why not just use an arrow function? https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#naming--self-this

Comment: Your edit makes this question obsolete.  You've basically answered your question by editing.

Comment: Your right, learn something every day ;) i was just trying it in the snippet, I returned it back the way it was to accept on of the answers below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow functions will do this for you.
Check out some explanations and [examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34361380/7103969).

Here's a corrected snippet:

```js
class thing {
  drawthing(thing) {
      console.log(thing);   
  }

  updatethings(thing) {
          // arrow func
          return new Promise((resolve) => {
               // another arrow func
               setTimeout(() => {
                   // Because of arrow function scoping, `this` passes through.
                   this.drawthing(thing);
                   return resolve(thing);
               },2000);
          });
      }
}

var t = new thing();
t.updatethings('hello').then(console.log);
```

Comment: This feels like it's missing some valid information that could help people learning like bound functions and static methods

Comment: I have referenced another article on SO that outlines those better than I could, and, no reason to duplicate it here.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a lambda/arrow function:

```
updatethings(thing) {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
           setTimeout(() => {
               this.drawthing(thing);
               return resolve(thing);
           },2000);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your method drawthing() will throw any exception or error then your promise will never get resolved and will eventually throw an exception.

You should also handle reject case in the time of exception like

```
 updatethings(thing) {
      var self = this;  //a better way to do this
      return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
           setTimeout(()=>{
              try{
                self.drawthing(thing);

              }catch(err){ return reject(err);}

              return resolve(thing);

           },2000);
      });
  }
```

And while calling your method your should also catch the exception.

```
t.updatethings('hello').then(console.log).catch((err)=> {console.log("handle error")});
```

Comment: I took all the error handling etc out, just to working out how to remove the 'var self= this' line

Comment: I thought you were just checking out the way of doing it. So gave a case. :) Cheers !!